# How to configure a pelican theme?

Tags: python, themes, pelican

I am going to use pelican for put up weekly updates at the last day of the week, I have got all setup , except I want the title to be having date followed by 'By User name'

basically I want to align date next to title then followed by  text "By Somebody"

but right now the basic theme of pelican is setup like this ![enter image description here][1]

I tried looking into the [basic theme](https://github.com/getpelican/pelican-themes/blob/master/basic/templates/base.html) folder but surprising there is no place I can spot where the word By or title is used , I am not familiar with this concept of creating blog post ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first step is understanding Jinja template inheritance. Then you can drill down into the templates as needed. For example, author information in the NotMyIdea theme is located in [article_infos.html](https://github.com/getpelican/pelican/blob/master/pelican/themes/notmyidea/templates/article_infos.html#L14).

Comment: the link you gave me is of `footer`. something that goes over Jinja template documentation in brief would be great

Comment: also, then the question is where is it extending from when it uses `{% extends "!simple/base.html" %}` ? i don't even have `simple` theme installed on the project path.

Comment: The link I provided has nothing to do with the footer. That template dictates what appears alongside article content (e.g., see right side of [Pelican blog](http://blog.getpelican.com/category/news.html)).

Comment: Jinja is a separate project, and there is plenty of information on the web regarding Jinja template inheritance.

Comment: The `simple` theme is [bundled with Pelican itself](https://github.com/getpelican/pelican/tree/master/pelican/themes/simple/templates), as is already explained in the Pelican documentation.

Comment: thanks, I am able to configure the simple theme for my requirements now.